# How do I fix a display which is truncated on the monitor?

Tags: windows, display

I have a Thinkpad running Win10. I plugged in a Dell E228WFP monitor. On it, The display is too large, and is truncated on the left and bottom.

When I go to the control panel to change the Advanced Display settings, it shows only the 1920x1080 resolution and there is no way to lower it.

The buttons on the monitor don't change the size either.

How can I fix it so nothing is truncated?

Comment: By default, your display will mirror that of your laptop.  In this mode, it MUST BE the lowest common denominator for both screens.  You didn't provide much information so I can only assume that this is the case.  Please try "Extend these displays" instead of "Duplicate these displays" and see what happens.  If you have already done so, please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the
[manual](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_display/dell-e228wfp_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf)
for the E228WFP monitor, the recommended and highest resolution is
1680x1050 at 60 Hz.

You could try to choose this resolution via
*Start > Settings > System > Display*, click "Advanced display settings",
select your display, click "Display adapter properties for ...",
then click in the Adapter tab the button "List All Modes".
If you see the resolution of 1680x1050, select it and click OK.

If the above method does not work, you could try to use the free
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)
to force the monitor's
[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data),
which is the information where the monitor tells Windows what it can do.

If you have an NVIDIA graphical card, you might be able do the same
as for CRU from the Nvidia Control Panel, section
*Display > Change resolution*.